# Javascript: how to save fetched data into a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, fetch

How to save fetched data into variable in javascript

```
const SWAPI_URL = "https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=10";

let darth = [];

fetch(SWAPI_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(darthVaderObj => {
        darthVaderObj
        darth.push(darthVaderObj);

    })

console.log(darth)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `console.log` statement is executed before the saving in `.then`. That's why you will get undefined. This is the expected behavior of asynchronous programming.

Basically, you need to do everything in the `.then` function in order to have the resolved value of the fetch.